# how to couting class variable in Python?

Tags: python

camera.py

```
class VideoCamera2(object):

    sample_num=0

    def __init__(self):
        self.webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.sample_num=sample_num
    
    def __del__(self):
        self.webcam.release()
    
    def get_frame(self):
        ret, frame = self.webcam.read()
        sample_num = self.sample_num + 1
        print(sample_num)
    
        if not ret:
            print("Could not read frame")
            exit()
            
        face, confidence = cv.detect_face(frame)
    
        try:
        ...
        except:
            ...

    ret,jpeg=cv2.imencode('.jpg',frame)
    return jpeg.tobytes()
```

If you want to add sample_num one by one, sample_num is always 1.
How do I fix the code to add one value to the sample_num?

Comment: Try initializing `sample_num = 0` variable outside of the class scope

Answer (score 0):

```
class VideoCamera2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize the instance variable sample_num as 0
        self.sample_num = 0

    def get_frame(self):
        # Add one to self.sample_num
        self.sample_num += 1


cam = VideoCamera2()
print(cam.sample_num)
# Output: 0

cam.get_frame()
print(cam.sample_num)
# Output: 1

cam.get_frame()
print(cam.sample_num)
# Output: 2
```

Comment: cam = VideoCamera2()
print(cam.sample_num)
# Output: 0

cam.get_frame() must be in the class. Is there any other way?